# Improve performance of ofstream

Tags: c++, file-io

I am writing strings to a text file using:

```
ofstream ofs("ofs.txt", ios_base::binary);
std::string str = "Hi";
for (int i = 0 ; i < 10000000 ; i++) {
    ofs << str.c_str();
    ofs << "\n" ;
}
```

However, this takes long time to execute. Can anybody help me how to improve performance of the above. Or any other faster way to writing strings to file.

Thanks.

Comment: why are you writing strings in binary mode?

Comment: You need to open the file in text mode only

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz, will that cause any performence overhead ?

Comment: @Subhajit Depending on the system, binary mode might be faster than text; at any rate, I don't think it will ever be slower.

Comment: @user1838343 Why don't you try and measure?

Comment: Why are you writing to the file 10000000 times? Just write it once and it will be much faster. You're forcing the OS to take a lock for every write and that's expensive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In several cases I found that C++ I/O streams tend to be slower than C `<stdio.h> FILE*`.

I had a confirmation also in the following test:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS // for stupid fopen_s warning
#include <stdio.h>
#include <exception>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

long long Counter() 
{
  LARGE_INTEGER li;
  QueryPerformanceCounter(&li);
  return li.QuadPart;
}

long long Frequency() 
{
  LARGE_INTEGER li;
  QueryPerformanceFrequency(&li);
  return li.QuadPart;
}

void PrintTime(long long start, long long finish, const char * s) 
{
  cout << s << ": " << (finish - start) * 1000.0 / Frequency() << " ms" << endl;
}

// RAII wrapper to FILE*
class File
{
public:
  explicit File(FILE * f)
    : m_file(f)
  {}

  ~File()
  {
    fclose(m_file);
  }

  FILE* Get() const
  {
    return m_file;
  }

  bool IsOpen() const
  {
    return (m_file != nullptr);
  }

private:
  FILE* m_file;

  File(const File&);
  File& operator=(const File&);
};

void TestIoStream(const vector<string>& lines)
{
  ofstream ofs("ofs.txt", ios_base::binary);
  for(auto it = lines.begin(); it != lines.end(); ++it)
  {
    ofs << it->c_str();
    ofs << "\n" ;
  }
}

void TestStdioFile(const vector<string>& lines)
{
  File file( fopen("cfile.txt", "wt") );
  if (! file.IsOpen())
    throw runtime_error("Can't open C FILE*.");

  for(auto it = lines.begin(); it != lines.end(); ++it)
  {
    fputs( it->c_str(), file.Get());
    fputs( "\n", file.Get());
  }
}

int main()
{
  static const int kExitOk = 0;
  static const int kExitError = 1;
  try
  {
    cout << "Building test lines...";
    vector<string> lines;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
      lines.push_back("Hi");
    cout << "done. ";
    cout << "(Count = " << lines.size() << ")" << endl;

    long long start = 0;
    long long finish = 0;

    start = Counter();  
    TestIoStream(lines);
    finish = Counter();
    PrintTime(start, finish, "C++ I/O stream");

    start = Counter();
    TestStdioFile(lines);
    finish = Counter();
    PrintTime(start, finish, "C FILE*");

    return kExitOk;
  }
  catch(const exception& e)
  {
    cerr << "\n*** ERROR: " << e.what() << endl;
    return kExitError;
  }
}
```

Compiled with VS2010 SP1 (VC10):

> ```
> cl /EHsc /W4 /nologo /MT /O2 /GL test.cpp
> ```

Test result:

> ```
> Building test lines...done. (Count = 10000000)
> C++ I/O stream: 2892.39 ms
> C FILE*: 2131.09 ms
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Just using `ofs << str;` might be slightly faster (or it might not be, but it's certainly more idiomatic).  But you're writing 20 megabytes of data; that's going to take some time, regardless of how you do it.

You don't say exactly what you're trying to do.  (I'm guessing that the real problem doesn't involve ten million times `"Hi"`.)  Depending on that, it might be possible to use low level IO, or even `mmap`.  But neither of these do any formatting, and if you have to format to a `ostringstream` first, you might find that they aren't significantly faster.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way to write a lot of strings to a file is (most likely) via the C `FILE *` interface. It is certainly fairly well documented that the C++ stream interface isn't as performant as the `FILE *`.

Ideally, if you build up a buffer of a few KB (perfectly, 4KB at a time), and write that using `fwrite(buffer, size_of_buffer, 1, outfile);`, you should get pretty close to the performance the system can produce. Yes, you can probably tune it half a percent or so more by using the native interfaces of `write` or `WriteFile` for Linux/Unix and Windows respectively.

The drawback of course is that you don't have an easy way to simply add an output method for arbitrary new types.

As always, when it comes to performance, measure the different options, and see which comes out best. If it's something that is going to be used on many machines under different circumstances, it's also good to test with different hardware, different amounts of memory and system load, to determine that you are not making just your machine run faster, but that it actually gives reasonable improvement [or at least no bad drawback] on systems with different conditions.